# Error al añadir objetos al arraylist Java

Tags: java

Estoy con un ejercicio de clase donde debemos almacenar artículos en un arraylist.

A la hora de añadir esos artículos mediante objetos, me da un fallo de que no se ha podido convertir a String. No entiendo por que pone eso, dado que los tres atributos son String. Os pongo lo que tengo. Haber si me ayudais a encontrar el fallo o solucionarlo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Clase Articulo:

```
    public class Articulo {
    //Creamos los atributos
    private String codigo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String existencias;
    //Creamos los Setter y Getters
    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getExistencias() {
        return existencias;
    }

    public void setExistencias(String existencias) {
        this.existencias = existencias;
    }
    //Contructor sin parametos inicializando codigo
    public Articulo() {
        this.codigo = "XX.000X";
    }
    //Contructor con parametros y los tres atributos
    public Articulo(String codigo, String descripcion, String existencias) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.existencias = existencias;
    }
    //Contructor con parametros, dos atributos y el tercero inicializandolo
    public Articulo(String codigo, String descripcion) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.existencias = "";
    }
    //Copia objeto
    public Articulo(Articulo copiaArticulo) {
        this.codigo=copiaArticulo.codigo;
        this.descripcion=copiaArticulo.descripcion;
        this.existencias=copiaArticulo.existencias;
    }

    public static boolean ValidarCodigo(String codigo) {
        boolean codigoValido;
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{1,3}[a-zA-X]{1,}$");

        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(codigo);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            codigoValido = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No has introducido bien el codigo, por favor intentelo de nuevo");
            codigoValido = false;
        }
        return codigoValido;
    }

    public static boolean ValidarDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        boolean descripcionValida;

        Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z\\s]{3,15}$");
        Matcher mat1 = pat1.matcher(descripcion);
        if (mat1.matches()) {
            descripcionValida = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No has introducido bien la descripción, por favor intentelo de nuevo. Recuerda que debe tener un mínimo de tres letras y máximo de 15");
            descripcionValida = false;
        }
        return descripcionValida;
    }

    public static boolean ValidarExistencias(String existencias) {
        boolean existenciasValida;

        Pattern pat2 = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,3}$");
        Matcher mat2 = pat2.matcher(existencias);
        if (mat2.matches()) {
            existenciasValida = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("El número introducido no es correcto, recuerda que debe ser positivo y que esté entre 1 y menos de 1000 ");
            existenciasValida = false;
        }
        return existenciasValida;
    }


}
```

Clase Almacen:

```
public class Almacen {
   private ArrayList<String> coleccion = new ArrayList(); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     //Objeto sin parametros
    Articulo prueba = new Articulo();
    prueba.setCodigo("XX.000X");
    prueba.setDescripcion(null);
    prueba.setExistencias("0");
    //Contructor con tres paramentros
    Articulo tornillos = new Articulo("AA.123A","tornillos", "9");
    //objeto con dos parametros
    Articulo tuercas = new Articulo("BB.111B","tuercas");
    tuercas.setExistencias("500");
    //objeto copia
    Articulo arandelas = new Articulo (tornillos);
    arandelas.setCodigo("CC.222C");
    arandelas.setDescripcion("arandelas");
    arandelas.setExistencias("500");
    coleccion.add(prueba);
}
}
```

Comment: prueba es de tipo Articulo no de tipo String proba a cambiar private ArrayList<String> coleccion = new ArrayList();  por private ArrayList<Articulo> coleccion = new ArrayList<Articulo>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen dos errores segun el codigo de ejemplo que publicaste:

1- El error que mencionas es porque intentas agregar un objecto a la lista de string(`private ArrayList<String> coleccion = new ArrayList();` ) para solucionar esto debes declarar que es un lista pero de objectos(Especificamente del objecto que quieres agregar : `ArrayList<Articulo> coleccion = new ArrayList();`)

2- El segundo error se debe a que en un metodo estatico no puedes acceder o tener acceso a una referencia o ninguna variable que sea estatica. Por ende, la lista debes declarar dentro de tu metodo main de esta forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Articulo> coleccion = new ArrayList();

    //Objeto sin parametros
    Articulo prueba = new Articulo();
    prueba.setCodigo("XX.000X");
    prueba.setDescripcion(null);
    prueba.setExistencias("0");
    //Contructor con tres paramentros
    Articulo tornillos = new Articulo("AA.123A","tornillos", "9");
    //objeto con dos parametros
    Articulo tuercas = new Articulo("BB.111B","tuercas");
    tuercas.setExistencias("500");
    //objeto copia
    Articulo arandelas = new Articulo (tornillos);
    arandelas.setCodigo("CC.222C");
    arandelas.setDescripcion("arandelas");
    arandelas.setExistencias("500");
    coleccion.add(prueba);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error esta dado básicamente, porque la variable de colección es de tipo `ArrayList<String>`.

debería ser de esta forma

```
ArrayList<Articulo > coleccion = new ArrayList();
```

ademas yo no la declararía como privada  (global) fuera del método,  si no que dentro del mismo método de esta forma:

```
List<Articulo> coleccion = new ArrayList<>();
```

en este punto según la versión de Java que estés utilizando debe pasar el nombre del objeto dentro de las comillas del nuevo `ArrayList`.

saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo declaraba private, por que lo pide el ejercicio...Sin private, funciona como lo has puesto, muchas gracias!